# How to get base64 like a get method

Tags: php

I want to use `Get` method to get my `base64` string. but I cannot get it:

```
  <?php
   $labels = $_GET['labels'];
   var_dump($labels);
   exsit();
?>
```

---

```
*****/chart.php?labels=WyIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAwOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMDowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDA6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAwOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMDoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDA6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAwOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMDozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDA6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAwOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMDo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDA6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAxOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDE6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAxOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDE6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAxOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDE6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAxOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDE6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAyOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMjowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDI6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAyOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMjoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDI6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAyOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMjozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDI6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAyOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMjo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDI6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAzOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMzowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDM6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAzOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMzoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDM6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAzOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMzozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDM6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDAzOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwMzo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDM6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA0OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNDowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDQ6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA0OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNDoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDQ6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA0OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNDozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDQ6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA0OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNDo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDQ6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA1OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDU6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA1OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDU6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA1OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDU6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA1OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDU6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA2OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNjowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDY6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA2OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNjoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDY6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA2OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNjozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDY6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA2OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNjo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDY6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA3OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNzowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDc6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA3OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNzoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDc6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA3OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNzozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDc6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA3OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwNzo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDc6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA4OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwODowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDg6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA4OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwODoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDg6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA4OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwODozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDg6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA4OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwODo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDg6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA5OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwOTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDk6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA5OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwOToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDk6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA5OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwOTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDk6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDA5OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAwOTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMDk6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEwOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMDowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTA6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEwOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMDoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTA6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEwOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMDozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTA6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEwOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMDo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTA6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDExOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTE6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDExOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTE6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDExOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTE6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDExOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTE6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEyOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMjowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTI6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEyOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMjoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTI6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEyOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMjozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTI6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEyOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMjo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTI6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEzOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMzowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTM6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEzOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMzoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTM6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEzOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMzozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTM6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDEzOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxMzo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTM6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE0OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNDowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTQ6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE0OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNDoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTQ6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE0OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNDozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTQ6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE0OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNDo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTQ6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE1OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTU6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE1OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTU6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE1OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTU6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE1OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTU6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE2OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNjowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTY6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE2OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNjoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTY6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE2OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNjozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTY6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE2OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNjo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTY6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE3OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNzowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTc6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE3OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNzoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTc6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE3OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNzozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTc6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE3OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxNzo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTc6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE4OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxODowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTg6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE4OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxODoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTg6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE4OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxODozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTg6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE4OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxODo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTg6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE5OjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxOTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTk6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE5OjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxOToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTk6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE5OjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxOTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTk6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDE5OjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAxOTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMTk6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIwOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMDowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjA6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIwOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMDoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjA6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIwOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMDozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjA6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIwOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMDo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjA6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIxOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMTowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjE6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIxOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMToyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjE6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIxOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMTozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjE6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIxOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMTo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjE6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIyOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMjowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjI6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIyOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMjoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjI6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIyOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMjozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjI6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIyOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMjo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjI6NTUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIzOjAwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMzowNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjM6MTAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIzOjE1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMzoyMCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjM6MjUiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIzOjMwIiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMzozNSIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjM6NDAiLCIyMDE4LTA3LTAxIDIzOjQ1IiwiMjAxOC0wNy0wMSAyMzo1MCIsIjIwMTgtMDctMDEgMjM6NTUiXQ==
```

but below sample works fine:

```
*****/chart.php?labels=test
```

Is there a limitation on server?

Comment: There is a kinda limit, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: might it be that the `=` padding at the end is being urlencoded causing it to fail when you convert it from its base64 encoding?